# Mongoose multi level markModified not working

Tags: mongoose

I have a schema with the a field exceptions, which has the schema type mixed.
The exceptions field is a multi level object of objects. I am marking all the paths that are modified in the object but the result is not saving.

Before the save I loop through the deep level key that I know is modified and do this.

```
_.forOwn(user.exceptions[date][mealTime], function(value, key) {
    user.markModified('exceptions.' + date + '.' + mealTime + '.' + key);
});
```

The output of user.modifiedPaths() is as follows.

```
[ 'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.meals',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.email',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.city',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.time',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.address',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.phone',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.zip',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.address2',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.instructions',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.date',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.type',
  'exceptions',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner',
  'exceptions.2014-01-28.dinner.cancelled' ]
```

I realise I can achieve the above through an update query, but I really want to use the post save hook.

Thanks

Joe